# Three quarters of the way back

Tags: meaning

while reading a book, I faced a sentence whose meaning I struggle to understand:

> This group its neatly tucked in the middle pews; three-quarters of the way back on Sunday mornings.

The context is about describing a group in the church. I specifically find "three-quarters of the way back" difficult to interpret. Does it mean the position they sit on, or that they constitute three quarters of those who participate in the worship service? Are there other ways to understand this expression?

Comment: Are you sure you transcribed the text correctly? Shouldn't it be "This group **is** neatly tucked...."?

Comment: I think you modified the original sentence thinking you would make it simpler and shorter. Instead, it's quite confusing. Can you please supply the title of the book or online story? Thanks.

Comment: Google throws up only three results, all stemming from this post, for [**"neatly tucked in the middle pews"**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22neatly+tucked+in+the+middle+pews%22&num=20&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjSqqbbq5_gAhUXGbkGHWDfBCUQ_AUICSgA&biw=1318&bih=603&dpr=1.1)

Comment: It's necessary to understand that, in many churches, the front several rows of pews will be largely unoccupied, such that "the middle" is farther back than one might expect.

Comment: My mistake. It should be "this group sits."

Answer (score 2):

It means roughly three-quarters of the way back from the front row of pews. If there were 12 rows of pews they would be sitting somewhere in rows 8 to 10. The term "the middle pews" is most likely to mean the central bank of pews between two aisles, the other banks being the "left and right" or "north and south" pews.

Comment: If there were 12 pews then the group would be sitting (approximately) in rows 5-7. How can this group of persons be in the middle if they are also 3/4 (rows 8-10) from the front row?

Comment: BoldBen might have a good point.  "Middle" here might reference left-right rather than front-back.  Often there are three sections of pews:  Left, middle, and right, with aisles in-between.

Comment: @Mari-LouA As I said I believe that "middle pews" refers to the central _columns_ of pews  not the rows. If we were talking about a theatre with 24 rows of 50 seats the people would be sitting somewhere around seat R25. If we are talking about rows in both cases then the statement is nonsensical.

Comment: My bad, I misread or completely missed the part which says "central bank of pews"

Answer (score 1):

The use of a semicolon is strange—since what follows is not an independent clause. It should be a comma instead.

However, *on Sunday mornings* also doesn't belong—unless a comma is placed before it as well or some kind of conjunction is used with the comma after *pews*.

---

The least amount of editing would be:

> This group [is] neatly tucked in the middle pews, three-quarters of the way back, on Sunday mornings.

---

Although it's not made explicitly clear, *three-quarters of the way back* is most likely referring to their position among all of the pews in general. So, while they are sitting in the middle pews, they are also sitting among the third quarter of pews.

---

Graphically, it would probably look something like this:

O O O O - First quarter of pews.
O O O O - Second quarter of pews.
O X X O - Third quarter of pews, in the middle, where the group is sitting.
O O O O - Last quarter of pews.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there is a typo and instead of *its* it is *is*. Right?

The subordinate clause after the semicolon is a restriction of the meaning of the predicate. The semicolon serves as a conjunction. You can understand the meaning of the subordinate clause, by repeating the subject and verb.

> *This group is neatly tucked* three quarters of the way back on Sunday mornings.

The whole sentence can be read as

> This group is neatly tucked in the middle pews, [but/and/but also/this is/...] this group is neatly tucked three quarters of the way back on Sunday mornings.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Please take the tour: english.stackexchange.com/tour and take a look through the help centre to familiarise yourself with our ways: english.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: We set mentions in italic, not as computer code. Please do not use markdown for computer code to indicate you are mentioning a word.

Comment: +1 for a viable alternative interpretation. If the rest of the context implies that the church is busier on Sunday, and that this group is submissive to other church goers (letting them go in front), then this interpretation is maybe more plausible than the left/middle/right pew columns.

Comment: @Pam It is not an alternative interpretation. It is the same way that all other answers read it. I only included an explanation of how it is mentally parsed.

Comment: Ah, the way I took it, it meant that the group were in the middle pews normally but on Sundays the church was busier so they had to sit further back. The other answers don’t imply different seats on different days to me, but technically the sentence could.

Comment: @Pam Ah, I see what you mean. Yes, well, that is due to the actual conjunction being omitted. That makes it ambiguous which one to choose. *And* or *but* both fit, but give different meanings. Honestly, in the answer I was more focused on the gapping of the subject and verb *This group is neatly tucked*, which is what is key to parsing the sentence. Once one mentally repeats the subject and verb in the subordinated sentence, then it is easy to understand, even if it remains ambiguous.